# Copy values from a column in one dataframe to another when a shared value exists in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames in R. The first is a list of species and a status code associated with them like below:

```
  taxon          status
1 Acer tom       LC
2 Carex geoff    EX
3 Carex bob      LC
4 Poa paul       LC
5 Juncus john    WL
```

The second is just a list of species like below:

```
  taxon
1 Acer tom
2 Carex clive
3 Carex bob
4 Poa paul
5 Luzula luke
```

What I'm looking to do is create a new column in the second data frame with the values from the status column in the first dataframe. As can be seen in the dataframes above though, some species will need to have a value of NA for status as they're not in the first dataframe.

I'd imagine this is an easy problem to solve, but my main issue is articulating the problem for google to help me!

Comment: That sounds like a simple join operation, e.g. `merge(df1, df2, by="taxon", all.x=TRUE)`, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: Just a comment that if you were trying to have Luzula luke have an NA with the code as suggested, it doesn't work for me.  Were you trying to have Luzula luke just removed? Will you post your code that worked please

Comment: ``` data <- data.frame(
  taxon = c("Acer tom", "Carex geoff", "Carex bob", "Poa paul", "Juncus john"),
  status = c("LC", "EX", "LC", "LC", "WL")
)

data1 <- data.frame(
  taxon = c("Acer tom", "Carex geoff", "Carex bob", "Poa paul", "Luzula luke"))

library(plyr)

results <-join(data,data1, type="full") ```

Comment: @Andy You can use a full join if you want to keep all values with NA added, e.g. `merge(df1, df2, by="taxon", all=TRUE)`